# INT comparison without WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Thread moved to: [INT comparison without WHERE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311246/int-comparison-without-where-statement)

Comment: What should be the output of your query?

Comment: Why do you need to do it without where?

Comment: You can't. That's not how SQL works: you need to put it in the WHERE clause (which is still part of the select as a whole).

Comment: I've been up all night but maybe use a self join with your 0 day function as the ON condition? Think question needs to be rethought

Comment: @simonatrcl He does not have to put something into `WHERE` when he wants to SELECT the number of days as a value, not as a condition.

Comment: No, but from my understanding he wants a condition.

Comment: OP said: *Because I want to also select for "Day 1" to "Day 5" at a later stage*. Just tell him how to select a date difference X.x @ThreaT what COLUMN TYPE is `date`? Is it `DateTime`?

Comment: @simonatrcl Not true. You can very much accomplish what the OP wants without using the WHERE clause here, using e.g. `IF` or `CASE WHEN`

Comment: Issues of data display are best handled in the presentation layer, assuming you have one. And don't use comma-join syntax - at least, not until you know what you're doing!

Answer (score 2):

Minor point, you have at least three syntax errors in your query.  There is the comma after Day 0, the lack of a date part in datediff(), and the double equal sign.  As to what you are trying to accomplish, it a case construct might be the way to go.

```
select case 
when datediff(day, date1, date2) = 0 then 'Day 0'
when abs(datediff(day, date1, date2)) = 1 then 'Day 1'
else 'something else' end WhatDay
from etc
```

You probably want a where clause so that you are not querying the entire table.  Doing that is rarely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiple columns then you only have one realistic choice, a `CASE` statement, but that's messy. However, with a little joining we can make it cleaner. Let's assume the key for the table is `Id`, we might write a statement like this:

```
SELECT t.*,
    CASE WHEN i.diff = 0 THEN 'Day 0' ELSE NULL END AS Day0,
    CASE WHEN i.diff = 1 THEN 'Day 1' ELSE NULL END AS Day1,
    CASE WHEN i.diff = 2 THEN 'Day 2' ELSE NULL END AS Day2,
    CASE WHEN i.diff = 3 THEN 'Day 3' ELSE NULL END AS Day3,
    CASE WHEN i.diff = 4 THEN 'Day 4' ELSE NULL END AS Day4,
    CASE WHEN i.diff = 5 THEN 'Day 5' ELSE NULL END AS Day5,
FROM table t
    JOIN (
        SELECT Id, DATEDIFF(
            STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), b.datetwo
        ) AS diff
        FROM table
    ) i ON i.Id = t.Id AND i.diff >= 0 AND i.diff <= 5
```

With this statement we now know what bucket each row falls into; if the value isn't `NULL`.